# Batch Script - Remove String From Line

Tags: batch-file

I need to remove "@DayZLingor181;" from the below line using only batch.

```
start D:\TCAFiles\Users\admin\5\bec.bat
call D:\TCAFiles\Users\admin\5\arma2oaserver.exe -Slots=40 -port=2332 "-config=cfgdayz\config.cfg" "-cfg=cfgdayz\basic.cfg" "-profiles=cfgdayz" "-BEpath=BattlEye" -name=cfgdayz "-mod=@DayZLingor181;@DayZ_Epoch;@DayZ_Epoch_Server;"
```

I have tried multiple different soloutions found on here but none give me the correct results.

I should be left with:

```
start D:\TCAFiles\Users\admin\5\bec.bat
call D:\TCAFiles\Users\admin\5\arma2oaserver.exe -Slots=40 -port=2332 "-config=cfgdayz\config.cfg" "-cfg=cfgdayz\basic.cfg" "-profiles=cfgdayz" "-BEpath=BattlEye" -name=cfgdayz "-mod=@DayZ_Epoch;@DayZ_Epoch_Server;"
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: This has to be done with batch as it is used to edit a users files on TCAdmin control panell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see `help set`:

> %PATH:str1=str2%

if we assume you have the line in a variable STR:

```
SET STR=%STR:@DayZLingor181;=%
```

replaces `@DayZLingor181;` with an empty string.

something like

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (file.txt) do (
  set STR=%%a
  SET STR=!STR:@DayZLingor181;=!
  echo !STR!>>newfile.txt
)
del file.txt
ren newfile.txt file.txt
```

Comment: How would I open the file before performing this?

    for /f "tokens=3" %%a in (myfile) do (

Comment: i was assuming basic batch knowledge, since you asked specifically about replacing a string.

Comment: This just outputs the following in a new file, without actually editing the original.

    start D:\TCAFiles\Users\admin\5\

Comment: there. completed it for you.

Answer (score 0):

As it stands this is case sensitive.

```
@echo off
type "file.bat" | repl "@DayZLingor181;" "" L >"newfile.bat"
```

This uses a helper batch file called `repl.bat` (by dbenham) - download from:  https://www.dropbox.com/s/qidqwztmetbvklt/repl.bat

Place `repl.bat` in the same folder as the batch file or in a folder that is on the path.